# mysql restore database script with create clause?

Tags: mysql, command-line, database-restore

```
mysql> -u username -p [database] < file.sql
```

restores database. I do not have a create clause in my dumped file, hence I need to create a database and then restore. I can do this to create.

```
mysql> create database [database];
```

Fair enough. Now how can I achieve the above restoration in one line? Is there anyway to restore a database by creating the database before that with a single line of code?

I can certainly live without it, but would be nice to know.. Thanks..

Answer (score 5):

`(echo "create database XYZ; use XYZ;"; cat file.sql) | mysql -u username -p`

could do the trick.

Comment: it outputs the given file after the output of the `echo` command. All together are piped into the `mysql`process.

Comment: This din work for me. I was preferably seeing for mysql solution itself. Something like `mysql> -u username -p --create [database] < file.sql` or so.. Anyway thanks, I learned something new..